# Apply Orbit File in snap for PALSAR 2 data

Tags: sentinel-snap, esa

I am using snap software for PALSAR 2 data. Thinking of orbit correction using the Apply Orbit File in the radar tool. But in the processing parameter, under the Orbit State Vectors we do not have any such option.How do i correct the orbital errors using SNAP only.